# trying to push each element with comma separated values also as an array element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below json object.

```
$scope.myDataList = [
  {name:"one,two"},
  {name:"three"},
  {name:"four"},
  {name:"five,eight,nine"}
]
```

I'm iterating the list and push the elements in the array as shown below.

```
$scope.myArray = new Array();
angular.forEach($scope.myDataList, function (value, key) { 
  $scope.myArray.push(value.name); 
});
```

I want to push each element with comma spearated values also in the array.
example:
When I print `$scope.myArray[0]`, it prints `one,two`.
But expected result is I want to print `one` for 
`$scope.myArray[0]` and `two` for `$scope.myArray[1]`, three for `$scope.myArray[2]`.

Each value with comma separation also I want to push as an array element.
I tried as below but does not work.

```
var array = $scope.myArray.split(',');
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/q36BQeqsj5GVNkP4PPhq?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the `name` and concatenate the result to the array instead:

```
angular.forEach($scope.myDataList, function (value, key) { 
  $scope.myArray = $scope.myArray.concat(value.name.split(',')); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with *AngularJS*, so I rewrote it in plain JavaScript:

```js
$scope = {};
    
$scope.myDataList = [{name:"one,two"},{name:"three"},{name:"four"},{name:"five,eight,nine"}]
  
$scope.myArray = $scope.myDataList.map(({ name }) => name.split(','))
  .reduce((result, splitElement) => result.concat(splitElement), []);
  
console.log($scope.myArray);
```

Note that the following line in your code

```
$scope.myArray.push(value.name);
```

pushes unsplit strings like `'five,eight,nine'` into `$scope.myArray`. This is not what you want. Also, `$scope.myArray.split(',')` will fail, since `Array.prototype` has no `split` function.

One way to achieve the correct result is to map over the original array and split every element (the result is an array of string arrays). After that, you can join the inner string arrays together using `Array.concat`. This is what the following two lines do:

```
$scope.myArray = $scope.myDataList.map(({ name }) => name.split(','))
     .reduce((result, splitElement) => result.concat(splitElement), []);
```

Comment: Ours are very similar approaches.  Is there a reason you did the two passes rather than `result.concat(name.split(','))` ?

Comment: @ScottSauyet No, this is just for illustration. I would probably write it like you myself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple means:

```
$scope.myArray = $scope.myDataList.reduce((a, {name}) => a.concat(name.split(',')), [])
```

Note that what you're trying to do is take the orginal list and create a new one.  Since it's not a one-for-one mapping, it's not `map`.  But `reduce` is appropriate, and carries more information than `forEach`.

```js
const $scope = {
  myDataList: [
    {name:"one,two"},
    {name:"three"},
    {name:"four"},
    {name:"five,eight,nine"}
  ]
}

$scope.myArray = $scope.myDataList.reduce((a, {name}) => a.concat(name.split(',')), [])

console.log($scope)
```

Answer (score 0):

while pushing the array element you can do:

```js
$scope.myArray = $scope.myArray.concat(value.name.split(","));
```

Here is the code to try.
http://plnkr.co/edit/nc91XI4vPJT0nEZvmMzU?p=preview